# Storing Matrices in Hash in R

Tags: r, hash

I am working on Storing the matrices as a key value pairs in R Programming using Hash Package, but I am facing some issue let me tell you my situation I have two matrices say matrix a, and matrix b, I want to make **matrix a**, as key and **matrix b** as a value for **matrix a**, I tried using the below script but it doesn't seem to work fine

```
a = 1 2  b = 5 6 
    3 4      7 8

dict <- hash()
.set(dict, a, b)
print(dict)

Actual Output
`1`
1 = 5

`2`
2 = 6

`3`
3 = 7

`4`
4 = 8

But I expect the output to be as

`1`
1 2     5 6
     =
3 4     7 8
```

How can I achieve this, do hash package support this kind of Operation or should I use any other package, any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, package `hash` doesn't support that kind of operation. (BTW, it's `hash`, with lowercase `h`, R is case sensitive.)
I have no experience with that package, but according to the manual, you can do something like the following.

```
library(hash)

# Data
a <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
b <- matrix(5:8, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

h <- hash(1:2, list(a, b))
h
<hash> containing 2 key-value pair(s).
  1 : 1 3 2 4
  2 : 5 7 6 8

h[["1"]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

h$`1`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```

Or, better yet, you can name the components of the output.

```
h <- hash(letters[1:2], list(a, b))
h
<hash> containing 2 key-value pair(s).
  a : 1 3 2 4
  b : 5 7 6 8

h[["a"]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

h$a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```

The class of the objects stored in `h` are matrices, as expected.

```
class(h$a)
[1] "matrix"
```

Note that, still according to the manual, you can avoid using function `.set`, you should use function `hash` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be interested in something like

```
library(hash)
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2,byrow = T)
b <- matrix(c(5,6,7,8),2,2,byrow = T)

a <- list(a)
b <- list(b)

dict <- hash()
.set(dict, a, b)
dict
```

Output is

```
c(1, 3, 2, 4) : 5, 7, 6, 8
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @shivanesh you should mark it as the correct answer if it answered your query as it'll help others in case they face similar issue in future. Thanks!